# Integral of $\frac{1+\sin \pi x}{(x^2+4)^2}$ on the interval $(-\infty,+\infty)$

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1+\sin \pi x}{(x^2+4)^2}\,dx
$$

Hi, I got this exercise to be solved but i got no idea on how am I suposed to do it. Can somebody show me how to proceed? Thank you!

Comment: 1) Integral from $\infty$ to $\infty$? 2) Do you mean to put parenthesis so that the integrand becomes $(1+\sin(\pi x))/(x^2+4)^2$? 3) No idea?? You must have some idea on how to work with integrals?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the integral of interest is given by

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1+\sin(\pi x)}{(x^2+4)^2}\,dx$$

and noting that

$$\frac{\sin \pi x}{(x ^2+4)^2}$$

is an odd function that is integtated over symmetric limits (in the Cauchy Principal Value sense)

we have

$$\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1+\sin(\pi x)}{(x^2+4)^2}\,dx&=\lim_{L\to \infty}\int_{-L}^{L} \frac{1+\sin(\pi x)}{(x^2+4)^2}\,dx\\\\
&=\lim_{L\to \infty}\int_{-L}^{L} \frac{1}{(x^2+4)^2}\,dx\\\\
&=2\lim_{L\to \infty}\int_{0}^{L} \frac{1}{(x^2+4)^2}\,dx\\\\
&=2\lim_{L\to \infty}\left(\frac{x/8}{x^2+4}+\frac{1}{16}\arctan\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right)\\\\
&=\frac{\pi}{16}
\end{align}$$

Note that since the integral $\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\sin \pi x}{(x ^2+4)^2}\,dx$ converges, we need not have interpreted the integral of interest in the sense of a Cauchy Principal Value.  The value of the integral was unaffected by this effective artifice of using symmetric limits.

Comment: Thank you! The part that was bothering me was $$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} sin(\pi x)/(x^2+4)^2dx
$$! Your help was appreciated :)

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure!